# Deploy ASP.NET CORE Application IN TO IIS

Tags: asp.net-core

Do we need really need to include following code in Program.cs .

.UseIISIntegration(),
.UseKestrel()

For deploying Asp.net core application in to IIS.

Regards,

krrish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to `the version of the core project` you are using.

In 2.2 and previous versions, you need to add .UseIISIntegration() and .UseKestrel() in Program.cs.

In 3.0 and future versions, **`ConfigureWebHostDefaults`** includes the functions of .UseIISIntegration() and .UseKestrel(), so you don’t need to add it manually.

More details, you can refer to this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58080353/application-is-running-inside-iis-process-but-is-not-configured-to-use-iis-serve).