# Problem hosting .net5.0 core web api on IIS (10.0.17763.1)

Tags: c#, iis, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

I am having problems hosting my .net core 5.0 web api on IIS so I decided to create a basic out of the box version (WeatherForecast). Again this would not work on IIS either (so its not my code I don't think). I have installed the .Net Core Hosting Bundle 5.0 (V5.0.2) and have restarted IIS (`net stop was /y`, `net start w3svc`).

My website is hosted at https://authdev.XXXXXXXX.net/api/weatherforecast (where XXXXXXXX.net is on my internal network). The server is Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2019. I have a separate app pool with .Net CLR version set to "No Managed Code" in an integrated pipeline mode. My website is set with appropriate bindings and configured correctly. I have confirmed this by creating a .Net Core 5.0 MVC website (out of the box) that works remotely from this server). I get a 404 in outofprocess mode (and the same url works locally with the obvious server url change). I added logging information at one stage and noticed that `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)` method in my Startup.cs does not get hit.

[Error message 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjV01.png)

I think this message indicates that my hosting environment is configured correctly, but that there is an error in my (out of the box) web api.

Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder
                    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .UseKestrel()
                    .UseIISIntegration()
                    .UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\WebApplication4.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 9f838b88-2902-4f1d-96d5-468aa0449fb0-->
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

I have tried running this in both inprocess and outofprocess modes

InProcess log

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[6]
      Application startup exception
      System.InvalidOperationException: Application is running inside IIS process but is not configured to use IIS server.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISServerSetupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Application is running inside IIS process but is not configured to use IIS server.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISServerSetupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at WebApplication4.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Working\dev\sandbox\WebApplication4\WebApplication4\Program.cs:line 17
```

OutOfProcess log

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://127.0.0.1:43593
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: e:\websites\auth-api
```

Comment: [Don't call `.UseKestrel()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58092138/712649) when hosting with IIS

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I removed the .UseKestrel() and redeployed. I get a 404 in both inprocess and outofprocess modes (I wouldn't expect outofprocess to work without kestrel). log file blank for inprocess mode, but the outofprocess has the familiar

info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://127.0.0.1:36553
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: e:\websites\auth-api

Comment: I can't test it right now, but perhaps the defaults changed and you have to explicitly call `UseIIS()` as well

Comment: Sorry, to be honest I have used all three `.UseKestrel()`, `.UseIISIntegration()` and `.UseIIS()` in various combinations with no success.

I think `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` sets some of this up automatically if missing but it just doesn't seem to give me the settings I need. I am curious why my `Configure` method isn't called in `Startup.cs` when using inprocess mode on the IIS server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that you are publishing as a self-contained package? Because if not, your configuration should look like this:

```
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet"
                  arguments=".\WebApplication16.dll"
                  stdoutLogEnabled="false"
                  stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"
                  hostingModel="inprocess" />
```

Comment: Hi Shawn, thanks for looking at this. I replaced this in my web.config changing the process path to ".\WebApplication5.exe" and the arguments to ".\WebApplication5.dll"

I get a 404 and the same error in the log `Application is running inside IIS process but is not configured to use IIS server.`

Comment: Ok, its working now. Thanks for all your help Shawn and Mathias

Comment: Shawn, your comments really helped. I don't think I have got it configured 100% correctly because inprocess still doesn't work, but it is now working with outofprocess.

Your comment about self-contained package prompted me to reconfigure my publish. It's now self-contained targeting win-x64.

The web.config now has `<aspNetCore processPath=".\WebApplication5.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="outofprocess" />` which seems to get things working. Also, I also made a mistake with my url it should have been .../weatherforecast not .../api/weatherforecast.