# "HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start" with IIS

Tags: c#, .net, iis, .net-core

I deployed a API .NET Core 5 service with the Publish feature. When I start the service with cmd with command `dotnet <service-name>.dll`, it runs but I cannot make API request. When I start it with IIS, it shows me the following error

```
HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start

Common solutions to this issue:
- The app failed to start
- The app started but then stopped
- The app started but threw an exception during startup

Troubleshooting steps:

- Check the system event log for error messages
- Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
- Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect
```

I searched around the internet this error, but I didn't find a solution for my problem. This is my `program.cs`

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder
            .UseNLog()
            //.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
            //.Build();
        });
```

Errors from EventViewer

.NET Runtime

```
Application: w3wp.exe
CoreCLR Version: 5.0.721.25508
.NET Version: 5.0.7
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException: Application is running inside IIS process but is not configured to use IIS server.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISServerSetupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at LogService.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\DEV\LogService\LogService.API\Program.cs:line 19
```

IIS AspNetCode Module V2

```
Application '/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\LogService\' hit unexpected managed exception, exception code = '0xe0434352'. First 30KB characters of captured stdout and stderr logs:
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[6]
      Application startup exception
      System.InvalidOperationException: Application is running inside IIS process but is not configured to use IIS server.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISServerSetupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Application is running inside IIS process but is not configured to use IIS server.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISServerSetupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at LogService.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\DEV\LogService\LogService.API\Program.cs:line 19

Application '/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\LogService\' failed to load coreclr. Exception message:
CLR worker thread exited prematurely
```

Comment: And are there any errors in any logs? (You may find it easier to get at the logs if you skip IIS, just for starting off.)

Comment: When you run in VS/VS Code does it works?

Comment: I experienced this because I had a buggy version of .NET Core 2.2 hosting package installed. It hosed out all other runtimes. I don't recall which one, but I updated it to the latest 2.2.x version and that took care of it for all other runtimes. Honestly though, this could be so many things....

Comment: Did you set .NET CLR Version to No Managed Code for application pool?

Comment: @JonSkeet I have 3 error logged, but they are the same type

Application: w3wp.exe
CoreCLR Version: 5.0.721.25508
.NET Version: 5.0.7
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException: Application is running inside IIS process but is not configured to use IIS server.

Comment: @Magnetron yes, it works on VS

Comment: @Crowcoder I have ASP.NET Core 5.0 Runtime (v5.0.7) - Windows Hosting Bundle

Comment: @LukasNespor yes, same problem

Comment: Okay, please add that more specific error into the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet check it

Comment: Right. That's better. Now hopefully someone who has encountered that error before will be able to help you.

Comment: See answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58092138/4584612

Comment: @LukasNespor I just saw that, nothing

Comment: You can try to delete the `webBuilder.UseKestrel()` and try again.

Comment: @samwu Goes on error 404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works with current configuration

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder
                .UseNLog()
                //.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                //.UseKestrel()
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseIIS()
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
                //.Build();
            });
```